# How clean activemq queue when messages are not cunsumed

Tags: activemq-classic

I am using ActiveMQ in my Java app. I am using a composite queue and in each one we use physical queues.

Is a way to give a timeout that if a message is not consumed in a specific time-frame it is deleted?

My problem is that some of the components that are supposed to consume the messages are not always working, hence my disk gets larger and larger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard, spec-compliant way to handle this is with the [`javax.jms.MessageProducer#setTimeToLive`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/MessageProducer.html#setTimeToLive-long-) method to tell the broker to only keep the message for a certain period of time.

If you don't want to change you code then you can make the broker do the work. In ActiveMQ 5.x you can use the [time stamp plugin](https://activemq.apache.org/timestampplugin). In [ActiveMQ Artemis](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/) you can use the [`expiry-delay`](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/message-expiry.html) `address-setting`.

Comment: Thanks , but I prefer without modifying the already running code